# AWS Serverless Environment setup with API Gateway, Lambda and Aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, amazon-aurora

Its a kind of GYM fitness IoT/Serverless project.

**Work Flow**

Each Member is wearing a fitness band on hands and it sends the data to the fitness mobile app every 30min via Bluetooth. Every day(7 am to 8 am) or when the user connects the mobile app to the internet, it will execute a Json call on the mobile app backend and send data to AWS API gateway, with the help of Lambda we will write the data to AWS Aurora. After that, each member can able to see the daily workout details in their fitness app.

> Need to setup an AWS serverless environment to handle n number of
> requests to the API Gateway. I've some doubts about setup the
> serverless environment

Questions:

1. How to handle a large number of queries comes to API Gateway (more
   than 10000/sec)
2. Did the lambda can handle the request? How to handle the data write to DB?
3. What kind of AWS Aurora is Suitable to handle the request.

Looking at your valuable suggestion to implement with highly scalable infrastructure.

Comment: From what you wrote, it does not seem to be a real-time data streaming app. Thus, normally you aggregate your requests. Instead of sending one json msg every second, you send 10 json messages as one payload every 10 seconds. Have you considered that?

Comment: @Marcin Let's consider realtime around 10000 members send the request to the API gateway. How I can handle the request in lambda and Aurora

Comment: If you really require 10000 function invocations per second, this may be a problem. Aurora and API gateway should handle that. So you could queue your messages in an SQS first, before invoking lambda directly. So, `APi gatway -> SQS -> lambda -> Aurora`. Can also ask aws support for increasing lambda concurrency limits.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks fo your info. I saw the AWS SQS https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/things-to-consider-when-you-build-rest-apis-with-amazon-api-gateway/ documentation. Could you suggest a better way to set up the Aurora, It has only one Writer, Is that Aurora with RDS Proxy is a good method ?

Answer (score 2):

> How to handle a large number of queries comes to API Gateway (more than 10000/sec)

API GW has limit of 10k requests/s with burstable capacity. This is a lot, so are you sure do you really need so much?

You may use SQS or  Kinesis for handling much higher throughput. (each option would have its pros and cons)

> Did the lambda can handle the request? How to handle the data write to DB?

The default concurrency limit for lambda is 1000 (increasable on request) , however using SQS or Kinesis could help to "smooth" the peaks and allow using more reasonable infrastructure.

> What kind of AWS Aurora is Suitable to handle the request.

As soon as you're using queueing of write events, you could select your instance types based on total throughput rather than be afraid of the peaks.

Comment: AWS Aurora or Aurora serverless is a better option for this?

Comment: @bibincatchme that would depend on your use case. Try out and see. When starting a new project or having sporadic access, it sounds reasonable to use the serverless option (I would). When in continuous production, you could save a lot having reserved instances (once you know how much of them do you need)